# Strange sequence of events

Tags: macos, bug

I was opening Discord and got the error "the application is not open anymore". I googled it and apparently it can happen sometimes, and I've to force quit. I went to open the Console app (which I haven't opened for a long while) to do that, and got the same error! repeated attempts didn't help.

Edit: to be clear, the second error happened opening the Console app. Not anymore related to Discord.

Then I went to restart, and it showed me a generic dialog about having to log out users or something. Don't remember well the text. The dialog was not responsive. I was able to click on "lock screen" back on the Apple menu, and then got a black screen just with the cursor. I had to force shut down the computer holding the keyboard off key. Started it again and seems to be working fine now.

Any ideas about this strange sequence of events? never experienced anything like this. It's an MBP m1 2021.

Comment: Your app crashed. It happens.

Comment: @Allan that was more than an app though, the same issue happened with Discord and the Console app, and then there was a black screen when locking the computer via the Apple menu.

Comment: Bad coding causes things like memory leaks. Discord consumes all memory and Console has nothing left to use.  No mystery

Comment: @Allan from my description it doesn't follow that it's likely neither a crash not a memory leak, the computer was not slowed down or otherwise unresponsive, and an error dialog with a message "the application is not open anymore" also would be atypical for such issues. There's also the issue with the unexplained exit to a defective lock screen, but don't bother with the details, I guess.